# Why there are dots at the beginning of my svg animation on firefox?

Tags: css, image, animation, svg

I am currently working on an svg animation.

Please, check this out on Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/seabon/s8o48yhk/

My CSS is very easy :

```
 #layer_1{
    width: 200px;
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    animation: anim 2s ease 1s;
}

@keyframes anim {
    to{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

Do you see the 4 dots before the animation ? I don't understand why.. It works perfectly on Chrome (with prefix) and Opera. 
I made my SVG image with illustrator.
Does anybody have an idea ?

Comment: I don't see the dots in Firefox. And I don't see the animation in Chrome.

Comment: i don't use prefix for the example. And you see the animation on Firefox ?

Comment: Yes. Firefox 38.0.1 on OSX Yosemite. (not dots)

Comment: I do, it looks like the very end points of the path(s) have kept the stroke. FF38 on W7

Comment: I am not crazy, http://hpics.li/d0eeccc there are dots before the animation. I use windows

Comment: Yep, I get that too.

Comment: That doesn't prove you're not crazy ;-)

Comment: No dots on Firefox on a Mac.

Comment: Maybe it's the svg code generate by Illustrator ?

Comment: I feel this is related to `stroke-linecap:round` if you comment that out they go away In FF. - https://jsfiddle.net/s8o48yhk/2/